# How to match path with regexp with path-to-regexp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, express

I have path to get user by his id:

```
/user/{id}
```

Then I transform it to regexp:

```
pathToRegexp(path.replace(/\{/g, ':').replace(/\}/g, ''))
```

And then compare it with

```
const matchedPaths = this.map.filter((obj: mapper) =>
  requestUrl.match(obj.regexp)
)[0]
```

But when I go to `/user/count` it thinks that I am going to `/user/{id}`.

Answer (score 0):

It will assume whatever you are passing as a parameter. If the same HTTP verb has been used. GET user/{id} --> GET use/regEx(anything) :: It consider regEx(anything) as parameter.

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.params.id)
})

     app.get(/.*fly$/, function (req, res) {
    res.send('/.*fly$/')
})

app.get(/.*plane$/, function (req, res) {
    res.send('/.*plane$/')
})
```

> only "/: id" -> Will run ::
>
> other wise both will run::